# Call functions from class which is in another Python-File

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, python-import, python-module

I have the following Problem in Python 2.7:
If I define 3 functions in a file "a.py",
and call these functions in another file, like:

```
import a
a.function1(arg1,...)
```

everything works fine.

But when I join this 3 functions in a class "B" in file "a.py", like

```
class B:
   def function1(arg1,...):

   def function2(arg1,...):

   ...
```

and call these functions in another file, like:

```
from a import b

b.function1(arg1,....)
......
......
```

this doesn't work.
What is wrong?

Comment: You need to be **clearer** with what doesn't work. "this doesn't work" is *not* a problem description. What happened instead? What was the full traceback?

Answer (score 4):

You named your class `B` with a capital B, but import `b`, lowercase.

Python is case sensitive, you'll need to match the class name correctly.